# xcodebuild Archive

Tags: iphone, ios, build-automation, xcodebuild

Has anyone been able to do just an archive from the xcodebuild command.
When I run

```
xcodebuild archive -workspace $workspace_name -scheme $scheme_name
```

I get the following error:

```
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace ws1 with scheme MyScheme.
    Reason: The selected run destination is not valid for this action.
```

I know some people have speculated that this is a bug in xcode 4.  Has anyone been able to find a workaround for this at all?

Thanks in advance